# Error: Notice: Undefined offset: index in ... when sum value same key in a array

Tags: php

```
$arrOne = array(
    '49' => 5
);

$arrTwo = array(
    '49' => 5
);

$myArray = array($arrOne, $arrTwo);
$sumArray = array();

foreach ($myArray as $k => $subArray) {
    foreach ($subArray as $id => $value) {
        $sumArray[$id] += $value;
    }
}

print_r($sumArray);
```

Result

> error: Notice: Undefined offset: 49 in

how to fix it?

I want result is: array(49 => 10)

Comment: @Anant Looks like error messages are disabled there - compare to [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/cDrMp).

Comment: `a += b` is somewhat equivalent to `a = a + b`. That means you're doing `$sumArray[$id] = $sumArray[$id] + $value`, when `$sumArray[$id]` obviously doesn't exist.

Comment: @Siguza   oh i got the point

Comment: haitruonginfotech please check the answers below and mark+up-vote one as a correct answer. you can up-vote too if they are useful too. thanks.

Comment: People are not responding. deleting my answer

Answer (score 2):

Because it's not defined yet, and you want to add (+=) to an undefined offset.
Change the inner code to below:

```
if (!isset($sumArray[$id])) {
    $sumArray[$id] = $value;
} else {
    $sumArray[$id] += $value;
}
```

Comment: @deceze, thanks for formatting as code. Somehow it kept giving error.

Answer (score 1):

Just initialise the index if it doesn't exist yet.

```
if(!isset($sumArray[$id])) {
    $sumArray[$id] = 0;
}
```

Patched into your code:

```
$arrOne = array(
    '49' => 5
);

$arrTwo = array(
    '49' => 5
);

$myArray = array($arrOne, $arrTwo);
$sumArray = array();

foreach ($myArray as $k => $subArray) {
    foreach ($subArray as $id => $value) {
        if(!isset($sumArray[$id])) {
            $sumArray[$id] = 0;
        }
        $sumArray[$id] += $value;
    }
}

print_r($sumArray);
```

[ [Demo](https://3v4l.org/1HJTP) ]